# Parallel GridSearchCV with custom Transformers hangs in IPython Notebooks

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have code in an IPython Notebook that uses sklearn's GridSearchCV with n_jobs = 4 to select parameters for a model in parallel.

It worked fine until I added custom transformers into the pipeline. As soon as I add a custom transformer into the pipeline it starts "hanging".. i.e. the process never completes, even though CPU usage goes down to zero.

When I set n_jobs = 1 it works fine even with custom transformers.

Here is code to reproduce the problem (copy&paste it into an IPython Notebook cell):

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

iris = load_iris()

X = iris["data"]
y = iris["target"]

class DummyTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X

cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=Pipeline(steps=[('dummy', DummyTransformer()),
                                            ('rf', RandomForestClassifier())]),
                  param_grid={"rf__n_estimators": [10, 100]},
                  scoring="f1_weighted",
                  cv=10,
                  n_jobs=2) # n_jobs = 1 works fine, but setting n_jobs = 2 makes the script run forever... :-(
cv.fit(X, y)

cv.grid_scores_
```

Set n_jobs=1 and it will work, set n_jobs to something >1 and it will never complete.

I use the IPython Notebook that comes with the Anaconda distribution. IPython Notebook v3.2, Python v3.4 on Windows 8 x64.

PS.: here's a Gist of the whole notebook https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95b65991e96f5361404c

PPS.: I just noticed that the "ipython notebook" process outputs the following error in the console window when the code hangs:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\pool.py", line 363, in get
    return recv()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DummyTransformer' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling I found the following sklearn issue:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2889

Where amueller says:

> "Try not defining the metric in the notebook, but in a separate file
>   and import it. I'd think that would fix it."

Putting the DummyTransformer into a utils.py and using "from utils import *" in the notebook really "fixed" it. I'd rather call it a workaround though.

**If anyone has a better/real solution, please add an answer!**